# jQuery goToByScroll offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, offset

I'm using the goToByScroll script and I need it to ignore the first 40px of my page because I have a fixed navigation, resulting in all positions being 40px too low.

Here's my code:

```
<script> 
  function goToByScroll(id){
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'500');
  }
</script>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Why `'html, body'` and not just `'body'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include the 40 pixels when calculating the offset...

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top - 40},'500');
```

Or maybe something like this...

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top - $("#nav").height() },'500');
```

And although @Praveen's answer is wrong, he puts a nice `.stop()` in there to prevent multiple firing from interfering with each other. Here it is alltogether...

```
<script>
  // assuming `#nav` identifies your navigation element...
  function goToByScroll(id){
      $('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top - $("#nav").height() },'500');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: 40 }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 
  function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top + 40},'500');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: should be `- 40` to move it down a bit, `+ 40` moves it up a bit, so the div becomes even more obscured by the navigation

Comment: I suppose that depends what you think "40px too low" means, the OP wording is a little ambiguous.

Comment: You make a good point - I guess I was assuming the navigation is at the top, so the content needs to be moved down more, but it is not clear.